# Generating Signed APK missing resource files

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-play, google-play-services

I'm generating a signed APK that I need to upload to play store. The issue I have is that the map I'm using makes use of a custom style and I'm referencing the custom styles from `Res>raw` folder. When I generate the debuggable APK/running the app on my phone the `R.raw.mapstyle_grayscale` file can be retrieved. When I try to generate a signed APK, I get the error `Error:(936, 98) error: cannot find symbol variable mapstyle_grayscale`

My code looks like this:

```
Boolean success = false;
int map_version = manager.getMapVersion(this);
 switch (map_version){
     case 0:
         break;
     case 1:
         success = googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapstyle_grayscale));
         break;
     case 2:
         success = googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapstyle_night));
         break;
     case 3:
         success = googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapstyle_retro));
         break;     
 }

if (!success)
    Log.e("Maps", "Style parsing failed.");
else
    Log.i("Maps","Style parsing successful");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `build.gradle` file and see if your `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` are set to `true`. If the `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` are set to `true` its removing the unused resources while generating a release apk. Normally resources which are referenced from the code can be found as a unused resource and hence the problem occurs.

If there are specific resources you wish to keep or discard, create an XML file in your project with a `<resources>` tag and specify each resource to keep in the `tools:keep` attribute and each resource to discard in the `tools:discard` attribute. Both attributes accept a comma-separated list of resource names. You can use the asterisk character as a wild card. Please [check here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#keep-resources) for more info.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@layout/l_used*_c,@layout/l_used_a,@layout/l_used_b*"
    tools:discard="@layout/unused2" />
```

[Developers guide for android](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) has more information about resource shrinking.

**Update:**

I came along with a similar issue during a custom signing process. The issue was, I was unzipping the apk and signing some library files and zipping the apk back again. While zipping the apk back again, the resource file was getting compressed and hence the reference to the resource file was missing in the singed apk. Hope that information might help any future developer.

Comment: minifyEnabled is set to false shrinkResources was false as well, I've tried to set it to true and add the above XML but the error being generated is still the same.

Comment: Please put your `build.gradle` and `proguard-rules.pro`.